# Imagen Hero no aparece

Tags: html, css

Tengo un proyecto el cual tiene una imagen de fondo a los laterales, y un texto en el medio de la página.

Hay dos problemas. Esta página tiene una *imagen hero* al final, pero no aparece, no sé por qué motivo.

Y el otro problema, es que el fondo de los laterales tiene que llegar al final de la página, pero añadiendo un `height: 100%`, hace el efecto contrario y la imagen desaparece completamente.

Actualmente, la página está así:

[image: pagina actual]

Cuando quiero algo como esto:

[image: pagina objetivo]

```css
.contenido {
 display: flex;
 text-align: center;
}

.lateral {
  background-image: url(https://i.pinimg.com/170x/17/4b/84/174b847e654ce1a04243cd1e3be7c944.jpg);
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  width: 15%;
}

.central {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* IMAGEN HERO */
.hero-image {
  background-image: url("https://dam.ngenespanol.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/perros-personalidad-2.jpg");
  height: 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenido">  
  <p class="lateral">
    
  </p>

  <div class="central"> 

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  
  <div class="hero-image">
   <!-- IMAGEN HERO -->
  </div>
  </div>

  <p class="lateral">
  
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La imagen inferior no aparece porque es el fondo de un div sin contenido y las dimensiones a mostrar son 0, si la incluyes como imagen dentro de ese div aparece, o bien añades contenido al `div` para que se muestre el background. Por la misma razón no repetía el background del lateral, ya que repetirá en función de las dimensiones del contenido del div central, puesto que los laterales (los he pasado de `p` a `div`) no tienen contenido propio. 
Se puede ver en el ejemplo.

```css
.contenido {
 display: flex;
 text-align: center;
}

.lateral {
  background: url(https://i.pinimg.com/170x/17/4b/84/174b847e654ce1a04243cd1e3be7c944.jpg) repeat-y;
  width: 15%; height: auto; 
}

.central {
  width: 70%;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* IMAGEN HERO */
.hero-image, .hero-image img {  
  width: 100%
}
```

```html
<div class="contenido">  
  <div class="lateral">
    
  </div>

  <div class="central"> 

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
  
  <div class="hero-image">
   <!-- IMAGEN HERO -->
      <img src="https://dam.ngenespanol.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/perros-personalidad-2.jpg">
  </div>
    
  </div>

  <div class="lateral">
  
  </div>
</div>
```